# DocuSign Using HTML in EmailBlurb

Tags: docusignapi

When creating an envelope through the API, if I put HTML in the EmailBlurb it gets escaped. Is there anyway to prevent this?

For Example, I need to put a link to a custom site with query parameters:

```
envelope.EmailBlurb = "<a href='http://www.google.com/?q=dynamic'>sample blurb</a>"
```

When the EmailBlurb shows up in the email the HTML is escaped:

```
<a href='http://www.google.com/?q=dynamic'>sample blurb</a>
```

Instead of:

[sample blurb](http://www.google.com/?q=dynamic)

Answer (score 1):

Your call is correct, there is an account setting that needs to be toggled on your account called `Allow HTML input in the API`

Contact support@docusign.com to get this enabled for your account. Be sure to include your account number and environment (Demo or Production).